# Save CSV with same name as current open CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv, save

I have a macro that runs a separate loop macro from personal workbook on a CSV (without opening it) and should re-save the document with the same name.

I get this error when it tries to save.

> Run-time error '1004':
> You cannot save this workbook with the same name as another open workbook or add-in. Choose a different name or close the other workbook or add-in before saving.

I need this as there is a tool looking for this document name.

This is the macro that opens the csv and runs the loop macro (without opening Excel).

```vb
Sub ExcelMacroExample() 
    Dim xlApp 
    Dim xlBook 

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\Folder\specific name.csv", 0, True) 
    xlapp.workbooks.open("C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART \Personal.xlsb")
    xlApp.Run "Personal.xlsb!LoopColumnC "
    xlApp.Quit 

    Set xlBook = Nothing 
    Set xlApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

The macro for LoopColumnC is where it tries to save.

```vb
Sub LoopColumnC()
    '
    ' LoopColumnC Macro
    '

    '
    'This is to disregard any popups.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'This is the actual loop. Works just fine. 
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = 1 Then Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i - 1, 3).Value
      Next i

    'Here is where it errors out because the file it is trying to save as is already opened in the background. 
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "F:\Folder\specific name.csv",

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are trying to save your personal workbook as the csv-file which is already open in the other instance of `Excel`. When you're using code from your personal workbook, you rarely use `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: So what would be the function to get it to save the csv that it updated and where would be the best place to put that code? In the ExcelMacroExample macro or in the LoopColumnC?

Comment: "without actually opening it" ... but you *are* opening it with `Workbooks.Open("F:\Folder\specific name.csv", 0, True)`. Then, why not just use `ActiveWorkbook.Save` instead of `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify your code to pass the worksheet object directly to the called macro - don't rely on Activesheet etc.

```vb
Sub ExcelMacroExample() 
    Dim xlApp 
    Dim xlBook

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    'if you want to save with the same name then you can't open as read-only...
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\Folder\specific name.csv", 0, True) 
    xlapp.workbooks.open("C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART \Personal.xlsb")
    xlApp.Run "Personal.xlsb!LoopColumnC", xlBook.Worksheets(1) '<< passes the sheet

    xlBook.Close '<<
    xlApp.Quit 

    Set xlBook = Nothing 
    Set xlApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Your processing macro receives the sheet object:

```vb
'gets a worksheet object from the caller
Sub LoopColumnC(ws As Worksheet)
  
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    'operate on the provided worksheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = 1 Then 
            ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, 3).Value
        End If
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Parent.SaveAs "F:\Folder\specific name.csv" 'ws.Parent = workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree with passing the worksheet object, but since `"F:\Folder\specific name.csv"` is literally the workbook being opened, shouldn't a simple `Save` suffice?

Comment: I thought that, but then wondered if those were placeholders, particularly as the OP opened the original file as read-only...

Comment: Yeah, that sentence "...(without actually opening it) and should re-save the document with the same name" is confusing then, since the workbook is actually being opened, and it's the same name (?).

Comment: Yeah. It actually does open excel but as like a "placeholder". I tried using a simple Save  and it prompts the save as file name box. I try to select it to overwrite the original csv and it tells me I cannot. 
I made the coding changes above and, as expected, get the error that it cannot save as the file was opened as a read only. To keep your changes, you'll need to save the workbook with a new name in a different location.

Comment: I did dig a little further and got it to work, using a 'IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended'


        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set xlBook = 
xlApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\Folder\specific name.csv", IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)   
... I also removed my extra Save function at the end of the loop since Excel asks when it closes anyways. Thanks for all the help! It is working correctly now.